# Adding a JScrollPane to an existing JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to add a JScrollPane (createTeamScrollPane) to a JPanel (createTeamPanel) that I have.  I have a frame, with a BorderLayout with the NORTH portion being used by a JPanel called tabMenu, and then the CENTER portion I would like my 'createTeamPanel' to have this scrolling ability as it will have more content than what I can fit on the screen at once. I am then adding both panels to the frame.  Currently the code as is runs but the window appears blank. Once resizing the window, I then see the 3 buttons in the NORTH portion of my frame (why is this happening?) and when I click on 'Create Team' it brings up the list of JLabels and JButtons I expect but I don't see any scrolling bars?

```
public static void main (String args[]) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("v0.01");
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    //frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel tabMenu = new JPanel();

    JPanel createTeamPanel = new JPanel();
    createTeamPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(createTeamPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    createTeamPanel.setSize(800, 700);
    createTeamPanel.setVisible(showCreateTeamPanel);
    createTeamPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);

    JScrollPane createTeamScrollPane = new JScrollPane(createTeamPanel);
    createTeamScrollPane.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 500);
    createTeamScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    createTeamScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    createTeamScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    //createTeamPanel.add(createTeamScrollPane);

    List<Player> teamList = MockTeams.initTeam();

    int xcoord = 100;
    int ycoord = 50;

    for(Player player : teamList) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(player.getName());
        label.setBounds(xcoord, ycoord, Constants.buttonWidth, Constants.buttonHeight);

        JButton addToTeamBtn = new JButton("Add to team");
        addToTeamBtn.setBounds(xcoord + 100, ycoord, Constants.buttonWidth, Constants.buttonHeight);
        addToTeamBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                myTeam.add(player);
                addToTeamBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        createTeamPanel.add(label);
        //createTeamFrame.add(label);
        createTeamPanel.add(addToTeamBtn);
        //createTeamFrame.add(addToTeamBtn);

        ycoord += 50;
    }

    JButton createTeamBtn = new JButton("Create Team");
    createTeamBtn.setBounds(0,0,150,20);
    createTeamBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //Hide/Show Create team panel
            if (!showCreateTeamPanel) {
                showCreateTeamPanel = true;
                createTeamPanel.setVisible(showCreateTeamPanel);
            } else {
                showCreateTeamPanel = false;
                createTeamPanel.setVisible(showCreateTeamPanel);
            }

        }
    });

    JButton manageTeamBtn = new JButton("Team Statistics");
    manageTeamBtn.setBounds(100,150,150,40);

    JButton resetBtn = new JButton("Reset Season");
    resetBtn.setBounds(100,200,150,40);

    tabMenu.add(createTeamBtn);
    tabMenu.add(manageTeamBtn);
    tabMenu.add(resetBtn);

    mainPanel.add(tabMenu, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(createTeamPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(mainPanel);

}
```

Expected result is to see a scrolling ability on the createTeamPanel but it is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I was able to add the JScrollPane to the mainPanel with:

mainPanel.add(createTeamScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);